# Creating dummy for states with year effect

Tags: stata

I have data of 18 states for 6 years(2009-2014).How can i create dummies which consider state and time effect simultaneously?

Comment: Cross-posted https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1401639-dummy-variables-for-two-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Without your data I have to assume a lot to answer this, but if I assume your `state` variable is a string and your `year` variable is numeric, then to create dummy variables for this I would put the two variables together and then `encode` them, like below:

```
tostring year, replace
gen state_year = state+year
encode state_year, gen(state_year_num)
```

and `state_year_num` is your indicator variable.

If you want a bunch of dummy variables you can add this line:

```
tabulate state_year_num, gen(dummy)
```

which will generate as many dummy variables as state-year pairs.

Comment: Helpful. `egen state_year = group(state year), label` would work regardless of whether variables are numeric or string. See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0034 for discussion. Then you can skip the `encode` and go straight to `tabulate`. Two lines, not four.